# Alternative to singleton wrapping native global state

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, native

In my application I'm writing an abstraction layer on top of a JNI library that calls into native C code. This native library (FFmpeg to be exact) exposes some global functions to change logging behavior.

In particular, I'm using a callback that forwards log messages to custom handlers. The problem is that there can be only one such callback. Creating a new instance of this callback means the native library will call it instead, whether it has been registered as the new callback or not. If you want another then you have to create a different callback class just like you'd declare a new function in C.

To me there seems to be two alternatives:

(1) Allow multiple instances of this singleton class. I'm already using a private static instance of the callback class. It cannot be instantiated elsewhere, at least, my subclass of this callback.

(2) Some other way to restrict users from instantiating this singleton class more than once.

The issues I have with the first approach are:

(1) The API is misleading. It's simply a proxy object that operates on global state. Yet to the user, it seems like each instance operates on its own state.

(2) Synchronization. I cannot use multiple locks. Using a static private lock takes us back to issue #1. At least a lock cannot be mutated of course.

Should I just give up on the whole thing and use a singleton anyway? No matter how you cut it, the class will be mutating global state. It's just that this state is beyond my control.

What to do in such situations? Do I have any viable alternatives?

Comment: So your problem is the native allows 1 function to be called and you need many.

Comment: Indeed. Just dealing with abstracting global state in native third-part libraries in general. Common sense is telling me to just use a singleton but my perfectionism is telling me to find a more OO alternative.

Comment: Is there any info in the callback you might use to route the calls? A video id int for example. Then you can secretly route the calls back to non-singleton handlers.

Comment: The register of handlers is part of the singleton. The handlers themselves are classes that implement a `LogHandler` interface, just like your answer suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the state is global in native, I would say it is best to model it as such in the API, and not give the impression that it isn't global.

> (2) Some other way to restrict users from instantiating this singleton class more than once.

It sounds like you don't have the best singleton implementation, see mine below.

You can maintain a list of your callbacks and invoke each of them when the native event fires:

```
public interface CallBack {
    void onWhatever();    
}

public enum WhateverEvent {
    INSTANCE;

    private final ArrayList<CallBack> callBacks = new ArrayList<>();

    public void register(CallBack callBack){
        callBacks.add(callBack);
    }

    private void theSingleRealCallBackTheNativeCalls(){
        for(CallBack callBack : callBacks)
            callBack.onWhatever();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
WhateverEvent.INSTANCE.register(new CallBack(){
   public void onWhatever(){
   }
});
```

If there is some info you can use to route it:

```
public enum WhateverEvent {
    INSTANCE;

    private final HashMap<Integer, CallBack> callBacks = new HashMap<>();

    public void register(int id, CallBack callBack){
        callBacks.put(id, callBack);
    }

    private void theSingleRealCallBackTheNativeCalls(int id){
        CallBack callBack : callBacks.get(id);
        if (callback != null)
            callBack.onWhatever();
    }
}
```

And then you can hide that in your API. And publicly it would appear to not be global again.

Comment: Actually, my private static callback already maintains a list of handlers. The callback is not the issue at hand. It's part of the problem dealing with abstracting native global state. I'm just looking to see what other developers would do or have done in such situations. But your answer seems to suggest I should use a singleton instead of trying to find a way to avoid it?

Comment: When the state is global in native, I would say it is best to model it as such. And not give the impression that it isn't global.

Comment: This particular callback doesn't supply an id. This is not a problem since the log message is forwarded to every registered handler. I could also forward it to the last registered handler. However, I do have other callbacks which do pass me a pointer to an opaque object. I used a dummy pointer (with the address being the id) and mapped it to the corresponding handler, as you suggested, and it worked! Nothing uses those pointers so no worries about illegal memory accesses. As for the design problem, I guess I'll have to live with the singleton solution. :)